# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable total_interest = num_payments(years * 12) * loanpayment(principal, percentage, years)

Tags: python

While I was in my coding session I ran into a problem about total interest.
I do know the equation for interest would be interest = num_payments * loanpayment - principal, but system keep giving me the error code of 
total_interest = num_payments(years * 12) * loanpayment(principal, percentage, years)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

```
def loanpayment(principal, percentage, years):
    i = (percentage/100)/12
    n = years * 12
    P = principal
    loanpayment = (i*principal*((1+i)**n))/(((1+i)**n)-1)
    return loanpayment

principal = int(input(""))
percentage = float(input(""))
years = int(input(""))
num_payments = years * 12

total_interest = num_payments(years * 12) * loanpayment(principal, percentage, years) - principal
total_amount = loanpayment(principal, percentage, years) * years * 12


print("Monthly payment : {}".format(loanpayment(principal,percentage,years)))
print("Total amount paid", total_amount, ".")
print("Total interest paid" total_interest, ".")
```

Comment: `num_payments = 12` and then `num_payments(...)` 

Answer (score 0):

```py
total_interest = num_payments(years * 12) * loanpayment(principal, percentage, years) - principal
```

`num_payments` is initialized as an integer. `num_payments(years * 12)` is invalid because integers are not callable. I think you meant to put a number there.

Comment: So, `num_payments(years * 12)` should be `num_payments` meaning this was a typo, right?

Comment: @Carcigenicate I mean, it was obvious what the cause of the error was. And it was more like 45 seconds.

Comment: This is possibly a misconception to do with mathematical notation; in mathematics we write `a(b + c)` to mean `a * (b + c)`, but in Python (and most other programming languages), it means calling a function named `a` with `b + c` as the argument.

Comment: but I did previously put num_payments = years * 12 and years was a input ?

Comment: So the (years * 12) after the num_payments are unnecessary part I see